# How to host VM images in GitLab docker registry

Tags: docker, kubernetes, gitlab, virtual-machine, virtualization

I would like to know if it is somehow possible to use the GitLab Docker registry to host VM images as well? My use case is the following:

We have a working GitLab CE installation. It is already possible to host Docker images in the Docker registry. We are using `kubevirt` to deploy VMs to kubernetes. The GitLab registry integrates nicely with Kubernetes, such that it is possible to pull Docker images from our GitLab registry and authentication is handled with a Kubernetes secret resource and `imagePullSecrets`. Now it would be great, if it was possible for Kubernetes to pull VM images to be deployed via `kubevirt` as well.

Any thoughts on this or other possible solutions are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little investigation I found a solution using GitLab and the [Containerzied Data Importer](https://github.com/kubevirt/containerized-data-importer). Basically, you create a Docker image that wraps your VM image and push this to GitLab as described [here](https://github.com/kubevirt/containerized-data-importer). By using the custom `DataVolume` resource, `kubevirt` is able to pull those images and create persistent volumes for use as VM disks.